# How to make HuggingFace model deterministic? (Informer)

Tags: python, time-series, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I am using Informer architecture and I noticed that even though I have set `torch.manual_seed(0)` the output of the model is still not deterministic and not possible to reproduce. How can I make it reproducible?

Comment: Please add an example of the code you are running.